# Values assigned by jquery not posting back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4 view i am assigning values to hidden during submit. But i am not getting that value back to the controller. Here is my code

```
@model Web.Models.FeaturedContactViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FeaturedSelected);
   <input type="submit" value="Update" onclick="return onSubmit()" />
}
@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSubmit() {

        var selectedOptions = $.map($('#FeaturedContacts option'),
                               function (e) { return $(e).val(); });
        $("#FeaturedSelected").val(selectedOptions.join(","));
        return true;
    };
</script>
}
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FeaturedContacts(FeaturedContactViewModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**FeaturedContactViewModel**

```
public class FeaturedContactViewModel
{
    public List<Contact> AllContacts { get; set; }

    public List<Contact> FeaturedContacts { get; set; }

    public int[] AllSelected { get; set; }
    public int[] FeaturedSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this the entire view, or only a section of it?  How is the content of the view model getting into your view?

Comment: I updated the model now.. pls check...

Comment: Have you checked that `FeaturedSelected` actually have a value?

Comment: yes i made a console.log during submit and the values getting printed

Comment: i traced the issue, the issue is `int[]` is not taking `string` values. Any idea of assigning `int[]` values with jquery ?

Comment: It looks like the reason you aren't getting your values back is because you have defined them as an array of ints, when in the HTML of the view, you are getting the values as strings.  Therefore, your view model's array isn't getting populated.  Do you get the values back in the controller if you define FeatureSelected as string[]?  You can always convert them to ints in the controller.

Comment: @JenniferS, ok thanks, wana update comment as answer and i will accept..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason you aren't getting your values back is because you have defined them as an array of ints, when in the HTML of the view, you are getting the values as strings.  Therefore, your view model's array isn't getting populated.  Do you get the values back in the controller if you define FeatureSelected as string[]?  You can always convert them to ints in the controller.